# App rejected because of Google Pay

Tags: android, google-play, google-pay

I wanted to submit my app for the beta in the Google Developer Console, but it got rejected. The mail Google send me said, the reason is an incorrect use of Google Pay. The thing is, I dont use Google Pay in my App at all. Also when searching my manifest for the line, Google said I should remove in my App when dont want to use Google Pay (

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>`

), I couldnt find anything.
I also dont want to sell any In-App pruchases and did say so in the Developement Console, the app is completely for free.

The build.gradle of the Module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myproject'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':copyoflibrary')
    compile project(':copyofHoloGraphLibrary')
    compile project(':multiStateToggleButton')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more info

Comment: I dont really have more info, I have no clue why it could be rejected except this mail, and that is in my eyes not understandable

Comment: Are you using any modules that declare the `<meta-data ...>`?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Is that the right one, or the one of the project?

Comment: Have your issue resolved? Even I am having same issue.

Comment: Not yet. I wrote at the Google Support though, and will update here, when I get an answer

Comment: This should be bug.. Because I am having same reason for the rejected. Hope this resolve soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the issue. If you are using google play from gradle as like below :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Then your debug and release manifest will have Android pay code as well It will auto include inapp purchase meta as well.

So you will need to select individual for each google service.

So if you are using GCM push notification, 
You gradle should be like

```
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
```

If you use google analytics then gardle will be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

I have checked released and debug menifest after made this change.

Thanks